# SQLite: How to include an Sqlean define statement in a `.sql` file?

Tags: functions, sqlite

I need to generate an SQL file containing UDF defined with the extension 'define' of [Sqlean](https://github.com/nalgeon/sqlean/tree/main).

Here is a minimum non-working `dump.sql` file:

```
SELECT load_extension('path/to/sqlean/define');
SELECT define('nn', 'coalesce(:x, 42)');
```

When I do:

```
sqlite3 a.db < dump.sql
```

It fails with:

```
Error: sqlite3_close() returns 5: unable to close due to unfinalized statements or unfinished backups
```

However, these statements work fine under the default `sqlite3` shell:

```
SQLite version 3.39.3 2022-09-05 11:02:23
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
Connected to a transient in-memory database.
Use ".open FILENAME" to reopen on a persistent database.
sqlite> SELECT load_extension('path/to/sqlean/define');

sqlite> SELECT define('nn', 'coalesce(:x, 42)');

sqlite> SELECT nn(NULL);
42
```

Surely something is missing from my `dump.sql` file, but what?

Comment: the function is added to the session and not a database

Comment: It may be an XY problem. How would I distribute an SQLite DB including a bunch of UDF? I need them in the triggers, among others, and are an integral part of the DB. I have already done this for MySQL and PostgreSQL, and would like achieve the same in SQLite.

Comment: the best option that i see  is to load the define extension when start of sql lite

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question. According to @nbk user, UDF are not part of the database, but of the session. Fortunately, SQLite offers a `.read` command which can execute a SQL file. So, under the SQLite shell:

```
.read dump.sql
```

... works perfectly.

Comment: i wanted to answer it right now